# Area bounded by $f(x) = -2(x-3)(x^2+1)$ and $g(x) = ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, definite-integrals, area

I have the following equations and trying to determine the value of a

$g(x) = ax$

$f(x) = -2(x-3)(x^2+1)$

Hello, I am trying to identify the unknown value of a > 0 such that the following holds: the region that is bounded by the y-axis, the plot of f(x), and the plot of the linear function g: R ! R with g(x) = ax, has area exactly 6.

I know for a start that I need to start with calculating the intersection of the two graphs and solve using the intersection of the two graphs as the boundary for the integral to find the area equal to 6.

the definite integral would be from boundaries 0 to the intersection f(x) - g(x) = 6 and solve for a?

[image]

this is a rough sketch of f(x) and y=x

But I can not find the answer as it is quite challenging.

Comment: i will also include a reference graph

Comment: My comment was incorrect, I misread which way your functions were labelled

Comment: Do you know how to find the intersection point as a function in $a$?

Comment: do i try and solve f(x) = g(x) ? but it seems very complicated would like so step by step explanations

Comment: i thought the value of 'a' is a scalar factor